# How to restore a postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I did a `pg_dumpall -c -f <BACKUP_FILE>.sql` on a system, I'd like to do a restore on another system and have postgres create all roles/databases/tablespaces for me, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the most recent PE uses postgres 9.4, I could without errors restore to a postgres server running postgres 9.5. My bad, should have checked the rpm's on the PE puppetDB server first.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly outlined in the PostgreSQL docs.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/backup-dump.html

**24.1.1. Restoring the Dump**

Text files created by pg_dump are intended to be read in by the psql program. The general command form to restore a dump is

```
psql dbname < infile
```

where infile is the file output by the pg_dump command. The database dbname will not be created by this command, so you must create it yourself from template0 before executing psql (e.g., with createdb -T template0 dbname). psql supports options similar to pg_dump for specifying the database server to connect to and the user name to use. See the psql reference page for more information. Non-text file dumps are restored using the pg_restore utility.